# High Water pressure

Tags: physical-chemistry

Say I had a laser drill that could cut a 2 km circle. I start it up in the deepest part of the ocean. I would then be cutting a 2 km circle straight for the earth core but just before I hit the liquid core. I shut off said drill. What would happen to the liquid ocean water at that pressure as it fall back in.

Comment: What is the pressure at the deepest part of the ocean? What is the temperature of the "liquid core"? Now you have a temp and pressure, look up the water phase diagram and see where you are. You are either gas, liquid, solid, supercritical fluid or somewhere on the boundaries of each of these regions.

Comment: This is not really on topic here. It might be acceptable on Earth Science SE but you will have to make it more specific and science based.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about chemistry.

Comment: If your interested only in pressure then read http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20009/hypothetical-what-happens-to-water-as-pressure-increases-to-infinity?rq=1

Comment: Sorry if put question in the wrong place

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean "you can remove a cylinder of material going all the way through the Earth, letting water go down?

If so, well, the Earth should survive. There will be a mighty earthquake. Several things to consider. Earth is liquid inside. So water will not be able to get all the way in. Magma will get there first. Next you will have water overheating at the water/magma surface. Magma will be cooling down. Water is an efficient coolant, so magma will solidify and the heat exchange will slow down.

The exact yield of the explosion depends a lot on how you are going to remove this cylinder. We should wait for a sound explanation how you can do it before we start calculation.

Laser will not work. You probably think of laser as something that evaporates stuff. You don't have any way for steam to escape from the bottom of the ocean, so first, you r laser will have to evaporate all water from oceans. But then, what will be flowing in that hole?

What effects are you looking for? High static pressure? Check experiments in a diamond anvil. Loud boom?  Using a laser that can drill a hole in Earth for just that purpose is a waste. Meteorites is your best way to go. You can even use your laser to direct them at/away from Earth. Evaporating material should create enough propulsion.

Comment: The mantle is **not** liquid. This is one of the most common misconceptions about the Earth's structure. The mantle is entirely solid (apart from very local melting near the crust-mantle boundary). Also, I fail to see why this will cause an earthquake. Earthquakes are caused by brittle fracture along faults.

Comment: This is actually quite good description of what would happen if such fragment of Earth suddenly disappeared. Of course it can't be done via laser or even meteor, but is nice thought experiment. @bon It isn't liquid but the hole would fill quickly due to incredible pressure down there.

Comment: It's just I seen this in Independence Day 2 and thinking about the science and thought it might be cool to talk about it a bit