# What would happen if I increase the pressure and temperature of a gas present in a container

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-chemistry, equilibrium, heat, pressure

Assume the gas to be a real gas and the container to be made of diamond or anything stronger than that. Take the amount of gas to be 2mL and the pressure is increased with the help of strongest pistons on earth. And the temperature is beyond the critical temperature of that gas in order to prevent phase change

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60984/will-supercritical-nitrogen-stay-supercritical-if-we-raise-temperature-and-press

Answer (score 1):

The gas would become solid, as the gas to solid transition does not have critical temperature, at least for usual orders of temperature. The needed pressure is just a question of the gas temperature. If we can achieve such a pressure is another question.

Comment: Is it applicable for all the gases?

Comment: All (real) gases. Just curious side info: helium is the only gas that cannot get solid at room pressure at any temperature. It needs several atm for that.